# Software package for Spatial-Spectral Image Fusion

Tags: images, image-processing, gis

I am involved in a remote sensing monitoring process for smallholder crops. I am using Sentinel-2 imagery (10m and 20m resolution) and also airborne imagery with 4 spectral bands and 1m resolution (B, G, R, NIR). I need to apply some image fusion process to increase the resolution of Sentinel-2 to 1m.

There are many methods in the scientific literature to perform image fusion. The [recent paper by *Yongquan Zhao & Desheng Liu - A robust and adaptive spatial-spectral fusion model for PlanetScope and Sentinel-2 imagery*](https://doi.org/10.1080/15481603.2022.2036054) presents a new method that seems very effective and compares it with other fusion methods. However, I haven't found any software package which incorporates any similar method and I don't feel qualified to implement any of these methods myself.

Does anyone know of any package/software that allows me to perform band-to-band image fusion?